# I need to write a SQL query which can fetch data and can b exported in XL sheet

Tags: sql

I need to write a SQL query which can fetch data and can b exported in XL sheet.

### Scenario

There are two tables A and B. B is a child of A and there is one to many relation (Means B can have many children of A). Now B has a column C which can have only two values 1 or 2.

### Requirement

I need to show in report - For each record of table A, count of "number of child records having value 1 in column C of table B", Count of "number of Child records having value 2 in column C of table B" and count "total number of child records in column C".

Comment: For what database?  Most have functionality to export to CSV, which Excel can read.

Comment: Not to mention that the ability to export to CSV has nothing to do with teh text of the question - this question appears to be about how to write the SQL statement.

Comment: I just want query..if it will fetch data in CSV, even then there is no problem. Database is ORACLE.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
select A.PK,
       sum(case when B.C = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalC1,
       sum(case when B.C = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalC2,
       count(B.C) as TotalChildren
    from A
        inner join B
            on A.PK = B.FK_to_A
    group by A.PK
```

Comment: Beat me to it!  Won't you also need to group by A.PK?

Comment: @mellamokb: Only if I want the query to run properly. :-) Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    A.PK,
    sum(case when B.C = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as CountOf1,
    sum(case when B.C = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as CountOf2,
    count(B.C) as TotalCount
from
    A
inner join
    B on A.FK = B.PK
group by
    A.PK
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I got the results. :)

Comment: @Vikram: Glad to help.  Please mark one of the answers as the correct answer to help the community.